# How to find out the amount of nested arrays inside the object of a JSON file with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, loops, object, each

I'm trying to find out the proper way to get a hold of the amount of nested arrays in an object within a JSON file. This got me a little messed up since I made the AJAX code with JQuery. I need this so i could use it as a number to be multiplied for in a random number generator.

I have already tried to use the `response.length` property inside the `Math.round(Math.random() * x + 1);` but it just returned the number 1.

JSON (people.json) :

```
[


{
    "name" : "Jason",
    "id" : "1"
},


{
    "name" : "Alek",
    "id" : "2"
},

{
    "name" : "Julian",
    "id" : "3"
}


]
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {



let url = 'data/people.json';
$.getJSON(url, function (response){

//let randomNum = Math.round(Math.random() * ~LENGTH~);


});//END getJSON 
}); //END OF READY FUNCTION
```

I expect the variable randomNum to return a number between 1-3 (The amount of nested arrays within my object in the JSON file.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [this](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users) link to get json but it is in the format that you've specified.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {



let url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
$.getJSON(url, function (response){
var length = response.length;
let randomNum = Math.round(Math.random() * length);

alert('random number is ' + randomNum);


});//END getJSON 
}); //EN
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @AlejandroCarvajalSarria if you found my answer helpful, please upvote it or add it as the accepted answer. That would be helpful for me.